# PyInstaller EXE file does not work on other computers - No Errors

Tags: python, pyqt, pyinstaller

I am trying to use PyInstaller in one-directory mode to freeze my Python program (in this case, a stripped down example). The resulting executable works on my computer, but will not work on any other computer. I turned the console (window) on, but no messages appear. I tried running the exe file from the command prompt, but again, no error messages. It appears to run part of the program (I tried putting in "print" commands, and they appeared in the console), but the GUI fails to appear, and the script just ends.

I was successfully able to freeze an example PySimpleGUI script, so I suspect this has something to do with mplwidget and PyQT.

**main.py**

```
# ------------------------------------------------------
# ---------------------- main.py -----------------------
# ------------------------------------------------------
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import*
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import (NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar)
import mplwidget # Added only to help PyInstaller find the file

import numpy as np
import random
     
class MatplotlibWidget(QMainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self):
        
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        loadUi("qt_designer.ui",self)

        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt5 & Matplotlib Example GUI")

        self.pushButton_generate_random_signal.clicked.connect(self.update_graph)

        self.addToolBar(NavigationToolbar(self.MplWidget.canvas, self))


    def update_graph(self):

        fs = 500
        f = random.randint(1, 100)
        ts = 1/fs
        length_of_signal = 100
        t = np.linspace(0,1,length_of_signal)
        
        cosinus_signal = np.cos(2*np.pi*f*t)
        sinus_signal = np.sin(2*np.pi*f*t)

        self.MplWidget.canvas.axes.clear()
        self.MplWidget.canvas.axes.plot(t, cosinus_signal)
        self.MplWidget.canvas.axes.plot(t, sinus_signal)
        self.MplWidget.canvas.axes.legend(('cosinus', 'sinus'),loc='upper right')
        self.MplWidget.canvas.axes.set_title('Cosinus - Sinus Signal')
        self.MplWidget.canvas.draw()
        

app = QApplication([])
window = MatplotlibWidget()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

**mplwidget.py**

```
# ------------------------------------------------------
# -------------------- mplwidget.py --------------------
# ------------------------------------------------------
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import*

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvas

from matplotlib.figure import Figure

    
class MplWidget(QWidget):
    
    def __init__(self, parent = None):

        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure())
        
        vertical_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        vertical_layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        
        self.canvas.axes = self.canvas.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.setLayout(vertical_layout)
```

**Code for the PyQT GUI - qt_designer.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_generate_random_signal">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>350</x>
      <y>100</y>
      <width>75</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>PushButton</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="MplWidget" name="MplWidget" native="true">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>79</x>
      <y>149</y>
      <width>661</width>
      <height>381</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>MplWidget</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header>mplwidget.h</header>
   <container>1</container>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

**Spec file for PyInstaller - main.spec**

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\ub714c\\Desktop\\example'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('qt_designer.ui', '.')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='main',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='main')
```